# Google Analytics: Ignoring URL segments - can it be done?

Tags: url, routes, google-analytics

I have a slightly unique issue whereby my web application has some URLs which look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/ext/b6bafaa21e9e8894458ee25038/members/home

http://www.mysite.com/ext/jd1323rij19f3f058ee25038/members/cool-page

http://www.mysite.com/ext/d428t9jmefb032b458ee25038/something/else
```

The first 2 segments of the URL is `/ext/SOME_UNIQUE_KEY/` which is needed for this particular site.

I want my Google Analytics account to ignore the first 2 segments and just track everything after this point **IF** the first segment is `ext`.

**Is this kind of customization possible?**

**How would I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use a regular expression filter:

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/04/regular-expression-tips-and-tricks.html

Comment: Specifically, the search and replace filter listed on this page to remove the unwanted url segment. http://online-metrics.com/google-analytics-filters/